# Laravel Auth::login not working on AJAX request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, and I am creating a login form which will be validated with Ajax. Now the problem is when I use **Auth::login($user)** it doesn't seem to login that user after email and password validation. Check my codes below.

**JS**

```
$('#loginform').on('submit', function(event){
    var token = $('#loginform input[name="_token"]').val();
    var email = $.trim($('#loginform #email').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#loginform #password').val());
    $.post("/checklogin",
    {
    _token: token,
    email: email,
    password: password,
    },
    function(data){
      if( data == "success" ){
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        $('#loginform .error').text(data);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**CheckLoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User as User;
use Hash;

class CheckLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function check(Request $request)
    {
        if( $request->ajax() ) :
            $user = User::where('email', '=', $_POST['email'])->first();
            if( $user ) :
                //check password
                if( Hash::check($_POST['password'], $user->password) ) :
                    Auth::login($user);
                    echo "success";
                else :
                    echo "Invalid username/password";
                endif;
            endif;
        endif;
    }   
}
```

Anybody please help.

Comment: what is the output `console.log(data)` in your ajax code `function(data)`

Comment: @h44f33z the console outputs "success" but still the user is not logged in.

Comment: maybe can try redirect to another route using `location.href` instead of `window.location.reload();`

Comment: The redirect is not the problem. But the **Auth::login($user)**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use `attempt` function to check the email and password. also use [laravel Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input) to get input

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' =>  $request->input('password')])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return 'success';
    }
    else {
        return 'Invalid username/password';
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh yeah will change that. How about the **Auth::login($user)**?

Comment: sorry @ClydeScope, my mistake that i did not notice you already do the password check using `Hash::check`. so the `Auth::login` should work the same, except the `attempt` is more simplified